# Можно ли оптимизировать блок с транзакцией EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, transaction

У меня есть много методов для взаимодействия с базой данных. Выглядят они так:

```
public async void Update(Pilot pilot)
{
    await using var transaction = await context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
    await transaction.CreateSavepointAsync("BeforeUpdate");
    try
    {
        context.Pilots.Update(pilot);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        await transaction.CommitAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        await transaction.RollbackToSavepointAsync("BeforeUpdate");
    }
}
```

Методы отличаются только тем, что находится в блоке `try`. Можно ли как-то оптимизировать конструкцию блока с транзакцией, чтобы код не дублировался?

Например, можно ли сделать что-то подобное, чтобы работало также как метод выше?

```
public async void Update(Pilot pilot)
{
    using (var customTransaction = new CustomTransaction())
    {
        context.Pilots.Update(pilot);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: update и так атомарный, зачем вам ещё транзакция?

Comment: Чем именно отличаются эти методы? / Метод `context.Update` может принимать объект любого типа.

Comment: Вообще, тут напрашивается паттерн Template method [Шаблонный метод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Шаблонный_метод_(шаблон_проектирования))